# Angular 11 - Call parent function from child

Tags: angular, typescript

I have used the passing of values ​​between Angular components several times correctly (Input/Output), but I found the following particular situation and  I cannot find the solution:

I have two components:

1. home.component (parent component)

The parent component, which in turn, contains another navigation component between tabs obtained from an external library, which is the one that loads the child component in a tab: "task.component":

html file:

```
<div>
<app-tabs [tabs]="tabs" [activeTab]="activeTab" (id)="onId($event)"></app-tabs>
</div>
```

ts file:

```
onId($event) {
    // $event would contain the id obtained in the child component
}
```

2. tasks.component (child component)

The child component contains the call from a button to call the parent component:

html file:

```
<button type="button" (click)="play('task/play', 30)">Play</button>
```

ts file:

```
@Output() id= new EventEmitter<number>();
play(url: string, id: number) {
this.tasksService.playTask(url).subscribe(
  response => {
    // From here, I need to communicate with the parent and access a method that is in the parent.
    // this.id.emit(id);
  },
  err => {
  }
);
}
```

In other cases, I pass parameters from the child to the parent without problems because I use my own components, but when using an intermediate tab component I do not get it. (is mandatory to use the tab component). I think it's logical that it doesn't work because the "Output" has to be passed directly to the component "task.component". That is, I cannot pass the "Output" "id" to the "app-tabs" component.

How could I do it?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that you want to pass data from grandchild to parent, skipping child?

Comment: I don't know the concept of grandchild well, but maybe it's this situation, "home" would be the parent, "tabs" the child and "task" the grandchild, the problem is that "tabs" is not a component created by me.

Comment: the "tabs" (child) component loads the "task" (grandchild) component using the "tabs" variable: this.tabs = [{id: 'tasksTab', label: 'Tasks', routerLink: '/task/' + this.id ];

Comment: What is the current implementation for (id) event on `app-tabs` ?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're not using a service?

Comment: I think that in this case I can't apply it, I will investigate it more carefully, since if I use a "ReplaySubject" service elsewhere to pass parameters between components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that child component (or grandchild component) is contained in a child route.

In this case, one solution could be to use a shared service to send notification from child component to parent. (or any other component inside application).

To do that, we need an injectable service (or integrated into an existing service) :

in `notification.service.ts` :

```js
@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
  _taskPlayed$ = new Subject<number>();

  get taskPlayed$() {
    return this._taskPlayed$.asObservable();
  }

  taskPlayed(id: number) {
    this._taskPlayed$.next(id);
  }
}
```

Be sure to add this service in module providers.

Then, we can inject service in child (or any component), and call `taskPlayed` method in order to emit a new value/event in observable.

So, in `child.component.ts` :

```js
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) {}

  playTask() {
    this.notificationService.taskPlayed(1);
  }
}
```

Same thing, we inject service in parent (or any component in app), and subscribe to `taskPlayed$` observable from service.
(be sure to unsubscribe when component is destroyed).

So, in `parent.component.ts` :

```js
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscription!: Subscription;

  constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.notificationService.taskPlayed$.subscribe((id) => {
      // do something with id...
      ....
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription?.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

In this example, only `id` value is sent via `Observable`, but we can also pass a more complex object.

```js
export class NotificationService {
  _taskPlayed$ = new Subject<{ id: number, title: string }>();

  get taskPlayed$() {
    return this._taskPlayed$.asObservable();
  }

  taskPlayed(task: {id: number, title: string}) {
    this._taskPlayed$.next(task);
  }
}
```

Comment: I use this system, that of subscribing to an observable through a service to pass data between components, in another part of the application and it works well, but I don't know if I could apply it to this problem, I'll try to comment here, thanks

Comment: It worked perfectly, I was applying the same technique to pass data in another functionality of the App and it doesn't occur to me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Perfect. you're welcome.